# How to loop through HTML rows and change the background if conditions are met in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<body>
  <div id="firsttablediv">
    <table id="firsttable" border="1">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Minimum Stock</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="insertfirsttable">
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>500</td>
          <td>1000</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="check">Check</button>
```

I want that when i press on the check button a loop runs through all rows and checks if the stock number is lower than the minimum stock then it changes that row background into red

Comment: What have you triead already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjuaf73e/

you'll need to include jQuery for this solution (which in my opinion every webapp should have).

Javascript code snippet:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    $('#insertfirsttable tr').each(function(){
        var cells = $('td', $(this));
        var stock = parseInt($(cells[1]).text());
        var min = parseInt($(cells[2]).text());
        if (stock < min)
            $(this).addClass('red');
    });
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity how would this be written in plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla-js,

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('firsttable').tBodies[0].rows;
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  for(var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
    var stock = +rows[i].cells[1].textContent,
        minStock = +rows[i].cells[2].textContent;
    if(stock < minStock)
      rows[i].classList.add('red');
  }
};
```

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('firsttable').tBodies[0].rows;
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  for(var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
    var stock = +rows[i].cells[1].textContent,
        minStock = +rows[i].cells[2].textContent;
    if(stock < minStock)
      rows[i].classList.add('red');
  }
};
```

```css
.red > td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="firsttable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Minimum Stock</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="insertfirsttable">
    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>5000</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: Works like a charm i just have one question in the stock and minStock variables why did you start with the '+' sign what does it do? because when removed the code doesn't work

Comment: @MuradElboudy That's the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29) operator. It converts the operand to a number. If you remove it, the comparison wil be alphabetical instead of numerical.